# Bash script; Cause processB to exit when processA exits

Tags: bash

Say I have a bash script that runs two separate processes together, like this:

```sh
trap "kill 0" EXIT

./processA &
./processB &

wait
```

This works great if all I ever need is to hit ctrl+c to exit both. However, if processA exits, processB continues to run.

What I need is a way to run processB that will cause processB to exit as soon as processA exits. (I don't need it to work the other way around though).

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/55922

Comment: @Niloct doesn't solve the problem. Ctrl+c works fine, I need processB to exit as soon as processA finishes.

Comment: What's wrong with `./processB & { ./processA; kill $!; } & wait`?

Answer (score 0):

While the comment of "oguz ismail" is working with me when I tested it, I'd like to make an easier to follow alternative:

```
trap "kill -9 0" EXIT

./processA &
P1=$!  # to save process ID to P1

./processB &
P2=$!  # to save process ID to P2

wait $P1  # assuming A will finish first, so wait for P1
```